# install package to sbin?

Tags: compiling

I have a downloaded tar and want to install it into `/sbin` for no other reason than a learning exercise. This is on a CentOS machine.

If I do `./configure --prefix=$HOME`

tar can be found in `/home/bob/bin/tar`

If I do `./configure --prefix=/tmp`

tar can be found at `/tmp/bin/tar`

but how do I get the binary into `/sbin`?

I know can make links, move it there etc. but how do I get it installed there from the start?

http://pastebin.com/hMUXShky

Comment: Have you tried --bindir, like your pastebin-link suggests?

Answer (score 1):

Yes that fixed it thanks very much.

```
./configure --bindir=/sbin
```

From the help I assumed this meant that it would still put the tar in some_locatation/bin/tar

```
--bindir=DIR            user executables [EPREFIX/bin]
```

But I was wrong. Thanks :)